# Send Cookies with HTTPWebRequestion through WP8 App

Tags: json, cookies, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

I have to send the cookies to server for every subsequent HTTPWebRequest. My code goes below.

```
class APIManager
{

CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
CookieCollection responseCookies = new CookieCollection();

private async Task<string> httpRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    string received;

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory
        .FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
    {
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                cookieJar = request.CookieContainer;
                responseCookies = response.Cookies;
                received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    return received;
}

public async Task<string> Get(string path)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(path)) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

    return await httpRequest(request);
}

public async Task<string> Post(string path, string postdata)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(path)) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
    using (var requestStream = await Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, null))
    {
        await requestStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    return await httpRequest(request);
}

}
```

Every time i ask for the question people say that i have to set the cookie container with request by following code line.

```
  request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
```

and i used it but still server returns the 'token does not match' error. Do i need to talk to the vendor for it?

Following image shows my problem and requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen you do something with the cookieJar !

```
//Create the cookie container and add a cookie.
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

// This example shows manually adding a cookie, but you would most
// likely read the cookies from isolated storage.
request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("http://api.search.live.net"),
new Cookie("id", "1234"));
```

`cookieJar` in your APIManager is a member, everytime your instance APIManager, the `cookieJar` is a new instance. you need to make sure `cookieJar` contains what the website needs.

you can have a look at this [How to: Get and Set Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920298%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: you got an eagle eye, in fact the code is older one. I changed cookiejar to static and verified that it had count 3 for the next call. Please let me know if making it static will work or i should persist the domain-ii (the cookie vendor told to persist) and then send it every time?

Comment: current code is         private static CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

Comment: static member still can be shared since static member belongs to the Class not the instance.

Comment: @LojiSmithKaleem you can try request.Headers["Cookie"]="your cookie";

Comment: request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("http://<domain>.com", UriKind.Absolute), responseCookies["cookietitle"]);

Comment: @LojiSmithKaleem I use cookie with `HttpClient` in my own project.

Comment: @LojiSmithKaleem for example, the web server need to verify your id, we send the cookie with the request with following code [sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373738/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-on-httpclients-httprequestmessage) and I think httpwebrequest works the same way [httpwebrequest cookie sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667931/httpwebrequest-add-cookie-to-cookiecontainer-argumentexception-parameternam)