# Why does request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "...") have no effect?

Tags: c#, cookies

I just encountered this strange behavior, which I can reproduce with the following code:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "/api/mymethod");
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "mycookie");
request.Headers.Add("Cookie2", "mycookie");
request.Content = new StringContent("<foo></foo>", Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
return httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

I then log the request with necat and I see that `Cookie2` is present, but `Cookie` is not!

```
POST /api/mymethod HTTP/1.1
Cookie2: mycookie
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:7777
Content-Length: 11
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<foo></foo>
```

It seems as if HttpRequestMessage goes out of its way to ignore the `Cookie` header, and I am wondering why it behaves like that.

And is there any way to force-add the Cookie? I suppose maybe they do it to enforce good coding practices, but right now I'm making a short throwaway script to automate a manual task (even the cookie is hardcoded in my code) and I was surprised at this behavior.

## Found answer:

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/13287224/492336, you can set an `HttpClientHandler` with `UseCookies` set to false, then it works:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = false }) { BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"]) };
```

Anyway, you should probably not use this for non-throwaway code.

Comment: You need a `CookieContainer`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164275

Comment: That would seem to be so. But I still wonder why `request.Headers.Add()` doesn't work - in general, code should behave in unexpected ways, and if I write `request.Headers.Add("Cookie")`, I certainly don't expect it to NOT ADD the cookie :)

Comment: Because that's the way Microsoft designed it.  Usually, when you create a new class like CookieCollection and then require people to use it, it means that 1.  You want a finer degree of control than a mere string will provide.  This is the basis for SQL parameters to avoid SQL injection, for example.  And, 2.  To provide additional functionality that a string alone won't provide.

Comment: Haha, yes. Anyway, the second answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373738/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-on-httpclients-httprequestmessage says I can put UseCookies=false in HttpHandler and then I can add it request.Headers.Add. Thanks!

Comment: The source code for CookieContainer is [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/cookiecontainer.cs), if you're so inclined.  Among other things, it supports the expiration of cookies, first-class URI objects, a hashtable for performance, cookie validation, thread safety and a number of other features.  It's about 1000 lines of code.