# How to get cookies from Fiddler?

Tags: c#, fiddler, xnet

I have starting to use xNet and I managed to log in to the website without cookies from a console application.

however, now I want to login to Roblox from Console Application but the problem is that I have to get the cookies to make it work.

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
    request.Cookies = new CookieDictionary();
    //request.Proxy = HttpProxyClient.Parse("127.0.0.1:9999");
    request.IgnoreProtocolErrors = true;
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.ConnectTimeout = 10000;
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134";
    request.AddHeader("Origin", "https://zenmate.com");
    request.Referer = "https://zenmate.com/";
    request.AddParam("Email", "example@gmail.com");
    request.AddParam("password", 123456);
    request.AddParam("cvalue", "ctype");
    var attempt = request.Post("https://auth.roblox.com/v1/login").ToString();
}
```

The main question is:

how can I get cookies to the cookiedictionary so the site will think I am a person and will let me Log In

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add cookies to WebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164275/how-to-add-cookies-to-webrequest)

Comment: oh, haven't seen that

Comment: it's not the same

Comment: Did you try that? How it is different?